# Extract words starting with @ in R dataframe and save as new column

Tags: r, regex, twitter

[image]My dataframe column looks like this:

```
head(tweets_date$Tweet)
[1] b"It is @DineshKarthik's birthday and here's a rare image of the captain of @KKRiders. Have you seen him do this before? Happy birthday, DK\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\xac                                                                                                                             
[2] b'The awesome @IPL officials do a wide range of duties to ensure smooth execution of work! Here\\xe2\\x80\\x99s @prabhakaran285 engaging with the @ChennaiIPL kid-squad that wanted to meet their daddies while the presentation was on :) #cutenessoverload #lineofduty \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x81 
[3] b'\\xf0\\x9f\\x8e\\x89\\xf0\\x9f\\x8e\\x89\\n\\nCHAMPIONS!!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[4] b'CHAMPIONS - 2018 #IPLFinal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[5] b'Chennai are Super Kings. A fairytale comeback as @ChennaiIPL beat #SRH by 8 wickets to seal their third #VIVOIPL Trophy \\xf0\\x9f\\x8f\\x86\\xf0\\x9f\\x8f\\x86\\xf0\\x9f\\x8f\\x86.  This is their moment to cherish, a moment to savour.                                          
[6] b"Final. It's all over! Chennai Super Kings won by 8 wickets
```

These are tweets which have mentions starting with '@', I need to extract all of them and save each mention in that particular tweet as "@mention1 @mention2". Currently my code just extracts them as lists.

My code:

```
tweets_date$Mentions<-str_extract_all(tweets_date$Tweet, "@\\w+")
```

How do I collapse those lists in each row to a form a string separated by spaces as mentioned earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str_extract_all` function from the `stringr` package returns a list of character vectors.  So, if you instead want a list of single CSV terms, then you may try using `sapply` for a base R option:

```
tweets <- str_extract_all(tweets_date$Tweet, "@\\w+")
tweets_date$Mentions <- sapply(tweets, function(x) paste(x, collapse=", "))
```

### Demo

Comment: That would have been my suggestion. Except, I would use `sapply(tweets, toString)`.

Comment: @JonGrub I agree with your advice.

Answer (score 4):

I trust it would be best if you used an asis column in this case:

extract words:

```
library(stringr)
Mentions <- str_extract_all(lis, "@\\w+")
```

some data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(col = 1:6, lett = LETTERS[1:6])
```

create a list column:

```
df$Mentions <- I(Mentions)
df
#output
  col lett     Mentions
1   1    A @DineshK....
2   2    B @IPL, @p....
3   3    C             
4   4    D             
5   5    E  @ChennaiIPL
6   6    F
```

I think this is better since it allows for quite easy sub setting:

```
df$Mentions[[1]]
#output
[1] "@DineshKarthik" "@KKRiders"  

df$Mentions[[1]][1]
#output
[1] "@DineshKarthik"
```

and it succinctly shows whats inside the column when printing the df.

data:

```
lis <- c("b'It is @DineshKarthik's birthday and here's a rare image of the captain of @KKRiders. Have you seen him do this before? Happy birthday, DK\\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\xac",                                                                                                                             
"b'The awesome @IPL officials do a wide range of duties to ensure smooth execution of work! Here\\xe2\\x80\\x99s @prabhakaran285 engaging with the @ChennaiIPL kid-squad that wanted to meet their daddies while the presentation was on :) #cutenessoverload #lineofduty \\xf0\\x9f\\x98\\x81",
"b'\\xf0\\x9f\\x8e\\x89\\xf0\\x9f\\x8e\\x89\\n\\nCHAMPIONS!!",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
"b'CHAMPIONS - 2018 #IPLFinal",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
"b'Chennai are Super Kings. A fairytale comeback as @ChennaiIPL beat #SRH by 8 wickets to seal their third #VIVOIPL Trophy \\xf0\\x9f\\x8f\\x86\\xf0\\x9f\\x8f\\x86\\xf0\\x9f\\x8f\\x86.  This is their moment to cherish, a moment to savour.",                                          
"b'Final. It's all over! Chennai Super Kings won by 8 wickets")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the `I()`. I was looking for just this the other day but did not actually know what to search for.

Comment: Yes, the `I()` was interesting, I hadn't seen that before; I was surprised to see the `AsIs` class has a different `format` method.

Answer (score 1):

Via Twitter's help site: *"Your username cannot be longer than 15 characters. Your real name can be longer (20 characters), but usernames are kept shorter for the sake of ease. A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z, numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above. Check to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols, dashes, or spaces."*

Note that email addresses can be in tweets as can URLs with @'s in them (and not just the silly URLs with username/password in the host component). Thus, something like:

`(^|[^[[:alnum:]_]@/\\!?=&])@([[:alnum:]_]{1,15})\\b`

is likely a better, safer choice